# Cedilla-accented "s" (ş) not working with tufte-latex AND MinionPro (other cedilla-accented characters do work)

Tags: accents, tufte, minionpro

I want to typeset the characters ş and Ş using the **tufte-book** document class and the **Minion Pro** font. The composed characters `\c{s}` and `\c{S}` work fine if I use either of the two packages but *not* if I use *both* packages at the same time, as seen in the following examples. For all the examples I also show `\c{c}` (ç) and `\c{C}` (Ç) which seem to work just fine in either case!

**Not working as intended:**

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\c{s} \c{S} \c{c} \c{C} 
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

**Only tufte-book works:**

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
\c{s} \c{S} \c{c} \c{C} 
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

**Only MinionPro (with \documentclass{article}) works as well:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\c{s} \c{S} \c{c} \c{C}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I cannot find out where both packages clash. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just for being sure: are you using XeLaTeX?

Comment: No, I use LaTeX using TeXShop (downloaded with the MacTex-2020 distribution) on a Mac. I think I use the default preferences.

Comment: better don't guess. Check the begin of the log-file: At least the first example with the boxes quite probably uses xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: The log-file says: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex)"

Comment: @egreg: *should* I use XeLaTeX in this case?

Comment: @Malte Not necessarily; however, I've never seen `pdflatex` printing boxes such as the one in your first image. I haven't `MinionPro` on my system and don't plan to do all the work for installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works using the `nofonts` option for the `tufte-book` document class.

```latex
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}
\c{s} \c{S} \c{c} \c{C}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

...as intended.

If someone can explain *why* this is the case, I'll accept their answer.